Number of iterations needed for the method of steepest descent
The function $f(x,y) = 4x^2 + 2y^2 + 2xy -4x + 6y$ has a unique global minimizer at $(x,y) = (1, -2)$
Starting at $(5,2)$ how many iterations of the steepest descent method would it take, at least, to guarantee that the value of $q(x_n, y_n) = f(x_n, y_n) - f(1,-2)$ is less than $10^{-8}$
I think I need to use Kantorovich inequality here but I'm not really sure what to do. Can anybody help?
